# How to get the number of unique ingredients per recipe id in a table of recipe ingredients. MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running a query that finds recipes that has specific ingredients in them. These ingredients are sent with the query e.g. "sugar, milk, egg".The recipes (recipe_id's) are then ordered by the amount of ingredients found in them, so if a recipe has sugar, milk and egg in it, it will get ordered before a recipe that only has 2 of the ingredients.

Query

```
SELECT
    recipe_id, COUNT(ingredient) AS ingredient_count
FROM
    ingredients
WHERE
    ingredient LIKE '%sugar%'
    OR ingredient LIKE '%milk%'
    OR ingredient LIKE '%egg%'
GROUP BY
    recipe_id
ORDER BY
    ingredient_count DESC;
```

Ingredients table

```
id | recipe_id | ingredient      |
---|-----------|-----------------|
1  | 1         | 2 cups of sugar |

...
```

Due to all the data being scraped the ingredients table has a bad structure. The ingredients are mixed with unit and amount e.g. "2 cups of sugar". That's the reason I have to use wildcards to find the ingredients. One recipe can also have an ingredient multiple times e.g. "1 cup of sugar" and "2 cups of sugar" (this is due to sub recipes), this is where I start to get problems. Because my where clause will find 2 "sugar" in a recipe the ingredient_count will increase by 2 (ofc), but I only want it to increase by 1 as there is only one ingredient, "sugar".

So what I want to accomplish is to somehow count all the ingredients the query returns BUT if an ingredient is found multiple times e.g. "2 cups of sugar", "1 cups of sugar" I only want to count that as 1, because they both have "sugar" in them.

This query does what I want with the counting but for some reason only returns very few recipes when it should return a lot more.

This query is not made by me

```
SELECT result.recipe_id, COUNT(*) FROM ( 
    SELECT
        recipe_id, ingredient
    FROM
        ingredients
    WHERE
        (ingredient LIKE '%sugar%')
        OR (ingredient LIKE '%milk%')
        OR (ingredient LIKE '%egg%')
    GROUP BY
        CASE
            WHEN ingredient LIKE '%sugar%' THEN 'sugar'
            WHEN ingredient LIKE '%milk%' THEN 'milk'
            WHEN ingredient LIKE '%egg%' THEN 'egg'
            ELSE NULL
        END
    ) AS result
GROUP BY result.recipe_id;
```

Comment: Find a way of cleaning up the data. It may be time consuming in the short term, but will pay massive dividends further down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expansion of @ast-tm answer:

That answer still didn't solve the "ingredient multiple times" double-counting.  Also, the original question wanted results Grouped by Recipe.

However, still I'm not sure it's technically giving you "the number of unique ingredients", only the number of Sugar-or-Milk-or-Eggs ingredients.  E.g. If a recipe had 10 other ingredients (not Milk or Sugar OR Eggs) those ingredients would be ignored in the counting altogether.

The idea of having to put into your query all the possible ingredient names is bad design in general.  And the query gets messy real-quick.  But in case it helps:

```
SELECT *, 
       IF(ingredient LIKE '%sugar%', 1, 0) as sgr,
       IF(ingredient LIKE '%milk%', 1, 0) as mlk,
       IF(ingredient LIKE '%egg%', 1, 0) as gg
FROM
    ingredients
    WHERE
        (ingredient LIKE '%sugar%')
        OR (ingredient LIKE '%milk%')
        OR (ingredient LIKE '%egg%')
GROUP BY
    recipe_id
ORDER BY
    (MAX(sgr) + AMX(mlk) + MAX(gg)) DESC;
```

I you wanted to also consider other ingredients, you could try moving your WHERE to a HAVING clause, and use GROUP_CONCAT (tho still doesn't solve the double-counting problem for anything but "sugar", "milk" or "eggs").

This may help get closer to what you need:

```
SELECT *, 
       IF((ingredient NOT LIKE '%sugar%' AND ingredient NOT LIKE '%milk%' AND ingredient NOT LIKE '%egg%'), 1, 0) as others,
       IF(ingredient LIKE '%sugar%', 1, 0) as sgr,
       IF(ingredient LIKE '%milk%', 1, 0) as mlk,
       IF(ingredient LIKE '%egg%', 1, 0) as gg
FROM
    ingredients
GROUP BY
    recipe_id
HAVING
        (GROUP_CONCAT(ingredient) LIKE '%sugar%')
        OR (GROUP_CONCAT(ingredient) LIKE '%milk%')
        OR (GROUP_CONCAT(ingredient) LIKE '%egg%')
ORDER BY
    (others + MAX(sgr) + AMX(mlk) + MAX(gg)) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, 
       IF(ingredient LIKE '%sugar%', 1, 0) as sgr,
       IF(ingredient LIKE '%milk%', 1, 0) as mlk,
       IF(ingredient LIKE '%egg%', 1, 0) as gg
FROM
    ingredients
    WHERE
        (ingredient LIKE '%sugar%')
        OR (ingredient LIKE '%milk%')
        OR (ingredient LIKE '%egg%')
ORDER BY sgr + mlk + gg DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can separate "unit" and "ingredient_name" into 2 separate columns, then you might accomplish it with this:

```
SELECT
    recipe_id, COUNT(DISTINCT ingredient_name) AS ingredient_count
FROM
    ingredients
WHERE
    ingredient_name LIKE '%sugar%'
    OR ingredient_name LIKE '%milk%'
    OR ingredient_name LIKE '%egg%'
GROUP BY
    recipe_id
ORDER BY
    ingredient_count DESC;
```

But what you are asking, is for MySQL to *know* that with a string like "1 cup of sugar", that "1 cup" and "sugar" are 2 separate values it can operate on.

However, *If you can Always count on* "of" being a separator, you *could*  try computing the *ingredient_name* on the fly using some clever use of MySQL string searching and chopping functions.  Tho very poor performance, this would replace "ingredient_name" in the above query with this:

```
SUBSTR(ingredient,LOCATE(' of ', ingredient)+4)
```

Comment: the ingredient unit and amount unfortunately look very different from time to time so i don't think that would work